# Проблема в отправке формы в PHP

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь через форму отправить письмо. Онако возникает затруднение на этапе получение данных из формы в обработчике.

**Форма**

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" name="f111">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" value="Your Name *" 
        onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
        onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="Your E-mail *"
        onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
        onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">   
    <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="message" cols="0" rows="0"
        onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
        onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
            Your Message *
    </textarea>
    <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="send message">
</form>
```

**Обработчик**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['$name'])) {$name = $_POST['$name'];}
if (isset($_POST['$email'])) {$email = $_POST['$email'];}
if (isset($_POST['$message'])) {$message = $_POST['$message'];}

$address = 'email@gmail.com';
$sub = "New Client";
$mes = "Name of client : $name \nAdress: $email \nMessage: $message";
$verify = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if ($verify == 'true')
{
    echo "<p>Ok";
}
else 
{
    echo "<p>Error";
}
?>
```

**Сообщение**

> To:email@gmail.com
>   Subject: New Client
>   X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:send.php
>   Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8
>   From:
>   Name of client :
>   Adress:
>   Message:

Comment: не приходит текст почему то

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Comment: а где форма отправки?

Comment: с формой все в порядке , проблема в том что форма приходит пустая

Comment: если форма приходит пустая значит не все в порядке

Comment: <form action="send.php" method="post" name="f111">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" value="Your Name *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="Your E-mail *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

Comment: <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="message" cols="0" rows="0" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Your Message *</textarea>
            <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="send message">
   </form>

Answer (score 5):

Вы не правильно обращаетесь к элементам суперглобального массива `$_POST`

Вы указываете индексы масива добавляя к ним символ `$` по аналогии с переменными, это не правильно. Уберите символ `$` в каждом индексе.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {$message = $_POST['message'];}
```